# Parsing abbreviated day of week to NodaTime.IsoDayOfWeek

Tags: c#, nodatime

How to parse abbreviated day-of-week name (e.g. 'Fri' or 'Sat') to `NodaTime.IsoDayOfWeek`? Preferrably looking for something that uses NodaTime built in pattern matching capabilities. If that's not possible, alternative approaches or workarounds are welcome. This does not have to be culture sensitive, okay to assume `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

I tried using `LocalDatePattern` "ddd" with a `LocalDate` template but it will fail unless the day of week I'm parsing (e.g. 'Fri') matches the template day of week. I could iterate over 7 different templates and return the first one that succeeds to parse but surely there must be a better way?

Comment: With pattern matching? I mean, what are your expectations?

Comment: Give this site a chance. https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/localdate-patterns

Comment: Does it need to be culture sensitive?

Comment: @Jodrell I have updated the question with a bit more details.

Comment: If you're happy to assume one specific culture, I'd just create a `Dictionary<string, IsoDayOfWeek>`. That's likely to be simpler than any other option.